# I'm trying to start Jupyter with Anaconda and the notebook doesn't launch. It doesn't display any error either

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I'm using Windows OS. I've just installed anaconda and i can see the notebook space. when i click on the jupyter notebook, nothing happens. There is a cmd running in the task manager but nothing else. I've tried a couple of methods out here but nothing makes a difference. My default browser is Chrome too.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a link starting with http://localhost/ in the terminal that you used to launch jupyter lab. Just copy that from the terminal and paste it in the browser.